# height of absolute div inside relative div

Tags: html, css, height, positioning

i have an absolute div inside a relative div and i want to make it of a fixed dimension. my problem is that the height is ignored.

this is my html structure:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="swipe">
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
body {
    background-color: #7ECEFD;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#swipe {
    background-color: white;    
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:10px;
    width:100%;
    height: 500px; 
}
```

why? how can i resolve it with css? any other trick (jquery)?

http://jsfiddle.net/nkint/XQzJf/

Comment: What makes you think the height is ignored?

Comment: You have an element with id="body", but your CSS has a declaration on the body *tag* (`body`, instead of `#body`). Is that intentional?

Comment: @ExplosionPills : if i change it.. nothing change.

Comment: @Faust : yes. you can ignore id="body"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `500px` high, but most of it is hidden due to the `overflow: hidden` on `#wrap`. You need to either remove that or make it big enough to contain `#swipe`.

Comment: ? what? overflow hidden is to hide its width.. what does it influence the height?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` hides it in both dimensions. If you only want it to apply to the width then use `overflow-x: hidden` instead.

Comment: true! but nothing has changed. can you manage to do it in the jsfiddle please?

Comment: Hmmm, that **is** strange. Removing the `overflow` rules altogether makes `#swipe` visible, but even explicitly setting `overflow-y: visible` doesn't.

Comment: Again, I'd suggest making `#wrap` tall enough to contain `#swipe`.

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body, #wrap {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: yesss!! i have resolved in the meanwhile but you answer is right!